# what is the best way to save libgdx values?

Tags: libgdx

I want to save values in my app game. I want an opinion on which is the best way.

I had thought of reading and writing text files of the values to be saved, but anyone who installs it on their phone / computer can modify the text file compromising the values even if they are encrypted. So I tried with the Preferences class but not having a physical document to be able to see at least in development is intimidating. What do you advise me to do?

Comment: How do you mean "even if they are encrypted"? If data is encrypted your app will know that data isn't valid so it can do appropriate action for that case.

Comment: for example, if I want to save the best score I can write it in a text file to save it, and if my score is 324 (example score) I can replace the 3 with c, 2 with b etc. The problem is that the user who installs the app can write random things to the file and compromise the saving. For now I have used the Preferences class but as I have already said I don't like too much as a solution because I don't have the physical file that I can check during development.
Have you ever created an app game in libgdx? If you did it like you did to save the data?

Comment: Yes, I do have few games. And I'm storing my data with prefs. Works fine for me. Generally if you don't have some sensitive data I don't think that you should worry much about someone trying to hack your game. I mean, if someone "hacks" highscore board on his phone - what would be the purpose of that? Whay would someone do that at all?

Comment: And again, if really needed, you can do some more serious encryption with i.e. checksum. So if content is randomly changes checksum check would fail and you'll know that data is corrupted.

Comment: ok, I'm going to inform you about this checksum

Answer (score 0):

On desktop there is a physical file placed in .prefs in your user directory (dependant from your os).

Comment: thank you! you believe it is the most appropriate way to save values, because then it is just like writing on text files and the user can change values, If you've ever created a game app with libgdx, how did you save the values? and do you know a method for not changing values for the user?

Comment: sorry, where are stored Preferences files in android phone?

Comment: They are stored in SharePrefs. libGDX is open source, you can view every source file by hitting Ctrl-Alt-B on the method.

Answer (score 0):

I use json and Base64Coder.  It encrypts all data and it seems to be pretty secure.  You can find more info in this tutorial https://youtu.be/GYULdO0Z_U8